# How can I theme the login form?

Tags: 8, theming, forms

I new in Drupal 8 and I have an a problem, i want to change de look of my `user_login_form`, reading about that i knew that i could use the `hook_form_alter` for my purpose but I can't access the form variables in the template of Twig. My hook is the next:

```
function halcones2_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_login_form':
      //Altera el formulario para añadirle una plantilla y poder imprimirlo             
    $form['#theme'] = 'halcones2_user_login';        
      break;
  }
}
```

To render the form to my template, that works but the form variables doesn´t appear like `{{ form.name }}` or `{{ form.pass }}` only I a can see de divs that i have in my template of twig.
My source to do that is the link https://nireneko.com/articulo/2018/05/personalizar-formulario-plantilla-drupal-8 but my problem is the form variables.
Someone can help me please??

Comment: Where is `hook_theme` implementation ?

Comment: Hi, well firstly like the link said (or I try to understand) it´s not necessary to implement de hook_theme if I use my template halcones2_user_login.html.twig to see the form, I try to use the halcones2_theme too but I don't know why when I use the 2 hooks in my halcones2.theme I receive an error but if I only put 1 hook in that file (halcones2.theme) I don't have any error but I don't see the variables form. My file .theme is in a sub-theme that I´ve created and it´s located in the root of my sub theme folder. My twig uses the route halcones2/templates/halcones2_user_login.html.twig .